# How to find the nearest value of two DataFrames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to find the closest value for every Element of a DataFrame from a second DataFrame.

I have two DF. The first DataFrame (DF1) contains 14.000.000 Elements.
I took a Sample DataFrame (DF2) which contains 30.000 Elements.

Now I want to find the closest Value for every Element in DF1 out of all Elements from DF2.

For example:

DF1:

```
Timestamp,                 Value
2014-01-01 00:00:01,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:05,       12.0
2014-01-01 00:00:09,       8.0
2014-01-01 00:00:10,       45.0
2014-01-01 00:00:15,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:21,       4.0
2014-01-01 00:00:32,       19.0
```

DF2:

```
Timestamp,                 Value
2014-01-01 00:00:01,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:10,       45.0
2014-01-01 00:00:09,       8.0
```

The Result should look like This:

`resultDF`

```
Timestamp,                 Value,     ClosestValue
2014-01-01 00:00:01,       3.0,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:05,       12.0,      8.0
2014-01-01 00:00:09,       8.0,       8.0
2014-01-01 00:00:10,       45.0,      45.0
2014-01-01 00:00:15,       3.0,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:21,       4.0,       3.0
2014-01-01 00:00:32,       19.0,      8.0
...
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be solved *efficiently* using one of the existing bucketing approaches: If your df2 is small, you could collect it, extract the bucketing intervals and then assign a bucket to each value. Look at Spark's histogram function for inspiration. I assume it requires a broadcast of your buckets.
Of course, if df2 grows beyond a few MByte, this method will start to become cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that your second `DataFrame` is small I suggest collecting its values and creating broadcast variable that can be used for searching closest element. Next step is to implement UDF responsible for finding closest element. I think that you can use binary search for this purpose, so that total complexity is `O(N*logM)`, where `N` - size of `DF1`, `M` - size of `DF2`.

### Step 1 - create broadcast variable

```
// we need to sort values to enable fast searching using binary search
val values = df2.collect().map(r => r.getDouble(0)).sorted
val valuesBroadcast = session.sparkContext.broadcast(values)
```

### Step 2 - implement binary search

```
def findClosest(element: Double, values: Array[Double]): Double = {
  var left = 0
  var right = values.length - 1
  var closest = Double.NaN
  var min = Double.MaxValue
  while(left <= right) {
    val mid = (left + right) / 2
    val current = values(mid)
    if(current == element) {
      closest = element
      left = right + 1
    }
    else {
      if(current < element) {
        left = mid + 1
      }
      else {
        right = mid - 1
      }
      val distance = (current - element).abs
      if(distance < min) {
        min = distance
        closest = current
      }
    }
  }
  closest
}
```

### Step 3 - create UDF

```
val findClosestUdf = udf((element: Double) => findClosest(element, valuesBroadcast.value))
```

### Step 4 - use UDF

```
df1.withColumn("ClosestValue", findClosestUdf(df1("Value")))
```

Comment: This answer is awesome  I'm wondering what about finding the closest element between 2 RDDs ?